# Issue deploying RoR app in CF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a RoR app using Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0, gem file below.  I can run the app locally but when I push to CF I get the following error without any helpful info.

```
2015-03-03T14:31:26.61-0500 [API]     ERR Encountered error: Staging error: failed to stage application:
2015-03-03T14:31:26.61-0500 [API]     ERR Script exited with status 255
```

I am using the CF community ruby buildpack (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git) since it seems to be the only one support ruby 2.2.

The command I am using to push is `cf push myapp -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git`

Gemfile:
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
ruby "2.2.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id
gem 'obfuscate_id', github: 'namick/obfuscate_id'

gem 'yui-compressor'

# https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted
gem 'attr_encrypted'

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 4.0"
gem 'capybara'
gem 'capybara-email' #, github: 'dockyard/capybara-email'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'guard-livereload'
gem 'guard-resque', github: 'railsjedi/guard-resque'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'faker'
gem 'pry-byebug'
gem 'pry-macro'
gem 'seed_dumper'
gem 'ruby-prof'
# Enough of these assets messages in log!
gem 'disable_assets_logger'
gem 'railroady'
end

# Testing
group :test do
gem 'simplecov', require: false
gem 'rubocop', require: false
gem 'rubocop-rspec', require: false
gem "database_cleaner"
gem 'timecop'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem "fakeredis", :require => "fakeredis/rspec"
end

group :development do
# gem 'binding_of_caller', '>= 0.7.1'
# gem 'better_errors', '>= 0.7.2'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.7.3.pre1'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-resque', '~> 0.2.1', require: false
gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'meta_request'
gem 'bullet'
end

# Database
gem 'pg'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'cf-autoconfig'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'apartment', github: 'influitive/apartment'

# Service object pattern
gem 'interactor-rails', '~> 2.0'

# Currency
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'google_currency'

# Analytics
gem 'ga_events'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# Twitter Bootstrap
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.8.1'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 3.1.3'

# Design stuff
#gem 'table_for_collection'
gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'
gem "font-awesome-rails"

# Static pages (without dealing with too many routes)
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'nestive', '~> 0.5'

# Social Network Sharing
# gem 'shareable'

# Front-end
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'draper', '~> 1.4'
gem 'humane-rails'
gem 'autonumeric-rails'
gem 'country_select'

# A/B Testing gem (remove for optimizely?)
gem 'split', require: 'split/dashboard'

# Structure js files and view integration
gem 'pluggable_js', '~> 2.0.0'

# Sign up wizard
gem 'wicked'

# Graphs
gem 'lazy_high_charts'

#Account management
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-xero', github: 'kaleworsley/omniauth-xero'
gem 'omniauth-freshbooks'
gem 'omniauth-quickbooks'
#gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
#gem 'omniauth-twitter'
#gem 'omniauth-facebook'
#gem 'omniauth-yelp'
gem 'pundit'

# Audit
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.5'

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

gem 'enumerize'
gem 'enum_help'


# External accounts
#gem 'xeroizer', '2.15.5'
gem 'freshbooks.rb'
gem 'quickbooks-ruby'
#https://github.com/cloocher/aggcat
#gem 'aggcat'

# MailChimp integration
gem 'gibbon'

# Contact us, https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form
gem 'mail_form'

# Page caching
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'

# Other helpers
gem "workflow"
#gem "httparty"
gem "resque", "~> 1.25.2"
gem 'resque-status'
```

Comment: What do you get in the log?: $ cf logs myapp --recent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up pulling a clean copy from git of my app and used the (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git buildpack and everything magically worked.  I think Cloud Foundry was trying to use an old version of a buildpack somehow...